# When to Use Rake Tasks in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm confused over whether it is the Rails way to place some code in a Rake Task or in a Model.

1. I have some code that is only run as a background job to send an email to a User if one of their friends had any activity for a day
2. I'm using the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to schedule the execution of the method/task which allows me to run the code from either the Model or a Rake Task

Can someone help me with this newbie question of if the Rails way would be to put the background job-only code in the Model or Rake Task?

Answer (score 1):

This as nothing to do with rails way but with object oriented programming. I would say you should place the behavior at a class so you can use it form every place in your app. If you place it at the rake task you would have behavior there. And this kind of rake task is to do something but who should know about how to do it should be the model or some other class. For example if you want to use resque in the future the changes to your code will be easier to do if you have it inside of a class and not locked inside a rake task.